# Android Dynamic Button Change background

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help me to change the background color of each button click? But I need to select only 1 button, If 1 button is selected, all of the other buttons will become unselected. The code is working fine and but I am willing to change this code if needed, I can get the unique id of each button when I clicked, see the image below. As you can see Toast 902 is the unique buttonId

[image]

MyActivity

```
GridLayout mGrid1 = findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
View dynamicCard;
CardView myCard;
TextView mTextView;
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
int setCardId;


for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
    addGridView(i, stringList);
}

private void addGridView(int index, String name) {
    initializeDynamicButton();
    mTextView.setText(name);
    setCardId++;
    myCard.setId(setCardId);
        
    mGrid1.addView(dynamicCard);
    
    myCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int cardViewId = view.getId();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + cardViewId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

private void initializeDynamicButton() {
    dynamicCard = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dynamic_layout_button, null, false);
    mTextView = dynamicCard.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_label);
    myCard = dynamicCard.findViewById(R.id.myCardView);
}
```

My XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_xl"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:columnCount="3"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Drawable
dynamic_layout_button.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_3dp"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/padding_small"
        app:contentPadding="@dimen/padding_2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_medium"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_label"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/flavor"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to place your buttons in a group tag and then add checkableBehavior

> ```
> <group android:checkableBehavior="single"> PLACE HERE YOUR BUTTONS </group>
> ```

If you would like to check which button is clicked, you have to first give each button an ID and then check if it is clicked or not. here's an example:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.button_a_id:
// handle button A click;
break;
case R.id.button_b_id:
// handle button B click;
break;
default:
throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but sorry this is for static buttons